# "shared global mode-line info"

Tags: mode-line

There's some stuff in the mode-line that's "global", not particular to that buffer, e.g. date-time-load, org-clock task and erc-track. If `split-window-right`, that stuff is both duplicated and truncated in the same way in both windows, e.g. here the org clock task name is truncated (scroll right to see the duplication):

```
27: 0 U ~/foo.el Top Elisp 12:19 [#ha] [1:31] [Procrast| 99: 0 U ~/foo.el 83% ELisp 12:19 [#ha] [1:31] [Procrast
```

Is there a way to truncate only the "global" stuff such that I get as much information as possible? E.g.

```
27: 0 U ~/foo.el Top Elisp 12:19 [#ha] [1:31] [Procras…| 99: 0 U ~/foo.el 83% Elisp 12:19 …tination]
```

(scroll right to see the non-duplication)

Comment: Put *last* whatever you want to sacrifice truncating to.

Comment: I already do ;) I know it's minor, but it's been annoying me for some years now …

Comment: … maybe I should try https://github.com/tautologyclub/feebleline/